# is there any way to show multiple image in one slider

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am working on codeigniter and i want to show multiple images on each slider and images i am getting from database , i am able to show one image but how can i achieve this

[image: I want this]

front end code is this

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="six-image">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/car.jpg') ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/car.jpg') ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/car.jpg') ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/car.jpg') ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/car.jpg') ?>">
                <img src="<?php echo base_url('/assets/images/car.jpg') ?>">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you have an array of data, which contains urls of images?

Comment: bootstrap 4 can help you https://www.codeply.com/go/FrzoIEKCdH/bootstrap-4-carousel-multiple

Comment: it will come from database and yes i will make a array and create a function select all

Comment: @uffusion 
i have slider but i want to make logic for backend to show images

Answer (score 0):

As you told, that you'll receive data from database and it seems like an array, lets take it as next:

```
$urls = ['/assets/images/car.jpg',
         '/assets/images/car2.jpg',
         '/assets/images/car3.jpg',
         '/assets/images/car4.jpg',
         '/assets/images/car5.jpg',
         '/assets/images/car6.jpg'
        ];
```

You can use `foreach` loop (or `for` loop, or `while` loop):

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="six-image">
                <?php foreach($urls as $item): ?>
                    <img src="<?= base_url($item); ?>"> 
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here `<?=` equal to `<?php echo`.

[Simplified Demo in PHP](https://3v4l.org/srVHc)

This way will give you 6 images in a row. You can apply third-party plugin and get carousel with 2 rows.

If you want to separate them with hard-code you can define HTML as next:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="six-image">
                <div class="row">
                <?php foreach($urls as $ind => $item): ?>
                    <?php if($ind % 3 == 0 && $ind != 0): ?>
                          </div><div class="row">
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <img src="<?= base_url($item); ?>"> 
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This way will give you 6 images in 2 rows.

If you're using `carousel` put next in the body of it:

```
<div class="item active">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="six-image">
                <div class="carousel">
                <?php foreach($urls as $item): ?>
                    <div><img src="<?= base_url($item); ?>"></div> 
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
    dots: true,
    slidesPerRow: 3,
    rows: 2,
    responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 478,
      settings: {
        slidesPerRow: 1,
        rows: 1,
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/><script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="carousel"> 
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://d.newsweek.com/en/full/520858/supermoon-moon-smartphone-photo-picture.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://d.newsweek.com/en/full/520858/supermoon-moon-smartphone-photo-picture.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://cdn.images.express.co.uk/img/dynamic/151/590x/Black-hole-picture-please-time-date-first-image-black-hole-event-horizon-telescope-1112295.jpg" alt=""></div>
        <div class=""><img width="60px" height="60px" src="https://d.newsweek.com/en/full/520858/supermoon-moon-smartphone-photo-picture.jpg" alt=""></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: you are right is working fine for one slider but i want that when user press next or previous button it should show other 6 images in next slider

Comment: @hassan, you need to know how does your plugin works. I'll show you how to implement `carousel`, next your turn.

Comment: yes you are right but i am stuck here as well because i do it with multiple items but i want to make a loop with in one items

Comment: @hassan, updated. `Slick.js` allows you to choose the number of rows etc.

Comment: okay thanks i will look into it is it work like if i have 12 images in database it will show 6 images in each slider?

Comment: @hassan, yes, 6 per slide, in 2 rows. In the `snippet` you see JS, here you can choose `slidesPerRow: 3,` - how many columns you see, and  `rows: 2,` - how many rows you need.

Comment: @hassan, as I said, you don't need to create a wheel, just find and use some carousel plugin and be happy.